# How to know this statement with classes & modulo is incorrect?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, relations

Suppose we try to define $\le$ on $\Bbb Z_m$ by saying that for $\hat x, \hat y \in \Bbb Z_m$, $\hat x \le \hat y$ if $x \le y$. What is wrong with this definition?

I am not too sure if I should show this by picking two values for $x$ and $y$ and finding an example.

Comment: To get $\Bbb Z$, use `\Bbb{Z}`; to add the subscript $m$ to it, use `\Bbb{Z}_{m}`. To get $\le$, use `\le`. There’s a MathJax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you! this will help so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $\hat 0, \hat 1 \in \Bbb Z_3$. You might say that $\hat 0 \le \hat 1$ because $0 \le 1$. On the other hand, $\hat 0 = \hat 3$, so we would also have $\hat 3 = \hat 0 \le \hat 1$. But wait, this would imply that $3 \le 1$! Do you get it now?

Comment: So the best way to show this is false is to give an example with numbers?

Comment: @Pam_22R: No, but my argument can be easily converted into a general one: if $0 \le a \le b < n$, then according to your definition we should have $\hat a \le \hat b$ in $\Bbb Z_n$. But since $\hat a = \widehat {a+kn}$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$, it would follow that $a+kn \le b$ for all $k \in \Bbb N$ which is not possible.

Comment: Why are you adding a and kn?

Comment: @Pam_22R: This is a bit like asking why do I have ideas that solve problems... A bit of practice will put you on the right track, I cannot explain how.

Comment: @Pam_22R: Unaccepting an answer without a good reason is very, very frustrating.

Comment: Oh sorry I was on another question in another tab and I must have confused the two

Answer (score 0):

Whether the definition works or not depends on what you mean by
$\hat x, \hat y \in \mathbb Z_m$.
Taking $\mathbb Z_3$ as an example,
we only need three equivalence classes and we really only need three
names for them, so our definition of $\mathbb Z_3$ could say
$\hat x$ is defined only for $0 \leq x < 3$, and
$\mathbb Z_3 = \{ \hat 0, \hat 1, \hat 2 \}$.

If that's how $\mathbb Z_3$ is defined then for 
$\hat x, \hat y \in \mathbb Z_m$, we already know that $0 \leq x < 3$
and $0 \leq y < 3$, and we will not cause any contradictions by
saying that $\hat x \leq \hat y$ if $x \leq y$.

On the other hand, if the definition of $\mathbb Z_3$
says that $\hat 3$ is another name for $\hat 0$, then
your definition of $\leq$ does not work.
(And yes, the way to show it does not work is to give an example
with specific numbers that shows a contradiction.)

So you really should make sure that whatever you're doing is
in agreement with the definition of $\mathbb Z_3$ that you happen
to be using in your particular context.
If it's an exercise for a university course, the textbook or
course notes should have given a definition of $\mathbb Z_3$ already
and that's the definition to use in that context, not the definition
you get from some random person on the internet or even from
another textbook.

Comment: Hmm well from my notes I have Z_m ={0,1,2,...,m-1}  so then the example given above would not work?

Comment: That's not really conclusive. If $\hat m$ were defined for $Z_m$ and $\hat m = \hat 0$, then you would still have $Z_m =\{\hat0,\hat1,\hat2,\ldots,\widehat{m-1}\}$. The fact that you _could_ have written $\hat m$ instead of $\hat0$ would not imply that you _must_ change the way you list the members of $Z_m$. A better way to decide would be to look at the definition of $\hat x$, which I hope is written precisely enough.

Comment: I am confused. My definition of say m=3 would be Z_m ={0,1,2} so then how would i procced to prove the inequality is false. I confused by what you mean about the definition of x. But i get that 3 could not be used then. I am rereading what you wrote for x and I sort of get it but not completely.

Comment: I have been using $\hat x$ for "class of $x$", but $x$ when it is just integer $x$ and not an equivalence class. Even when people write literally $Z_3=\{0,1,2\}$, usually what they _intend_ is $Z_3=\{\hat 0,\hat 1,\hat 2\}$ (or whatever notation you prefer for "class of"). My recollection of the definitions is "class of $x$" is defined for every integer $x$, i.e. you can always write $\hat x$, with $\hat0=\hat3=\hat6=\cdots$. But the point is the words and symbols must be defined somewhere, and only by looking at definition that _you_ received can you be sure you're using it correctly.

Comment: Yes I mean the class of x I just do not know how to write it here. So I am confused by how to solve this problem now. Because I was also told by my professor that hat m = hat 0 and hat m+1=hat 1, etc...

Comment: OK, so you _are_ using the same definitions I would expect, and the answer by Alex is correct. Sorry for the confusion! I just wanted to be sure your professor agreed with the definitions we are accustomed to.

Comment: By the way, in order to write math symbols in your next question, refer to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: yes, I am going by my professor's definition as well because I realize this would affect my answer overall. and its okay! I appreciate the extra help because this really could have affected my answer.